# Reusing a UI of an existing document as part of another process/view

Tags: skyve

I have a use case where users can register themselves. Once registered, the users become "members". There is a Skyve document describing "members"

As part of the registering process the registering user pretty much needs to enter all the information on the "members" document.

I have a registration document describing the registration process, it has a few steps, one of which is to enter the users information. I have an association to the member document in the registration document. Is there anyway of re/using the original member documents create view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bound view component to achieve this.

See https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/views/#view-components

```
<component binding="member" />
```

will inline the Member document view (create or edit depending on the whether the underlying bean is persisted or not).

You can also name the view component for the target document the binding references to make things explicit.

```
<component binding="member" name="create" />
```